# Firebase V9 Query with Multiple Conditions, Sorting by ID, and Pagination Problem

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase which are paginated.

my problem is located in the dataRef variable.
I would like to pass several conditions in the query, e.g.:

`where('category', '==', 'men') where('id', '>', '50') where('price', '>', '100')`
...

**then I want to sort the final result by id**

and do pagination using startAt, endAt.

if I comment out these 3 lines the code works. Otherwise I get an empty array. Does anyone know if firebase provides any other solutions, or knows how to do it?

`orderBy('id'), startAt(49), endAt(69)`

```
const queryConditions = categoryQuery.map((query) =>
where(query.fieldPath, query.opStr, query.value)
);
const dataRef = query(
collection(firestore, 'shirts'),
// or(...queryConditions),
and(where('category', '==', 'men'), where('id', '==', 11)),
orderBy('id'),
startAt(49),
endAt(69)
);
const snapshot = await getDocs(dataRef);
const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
const validatedData = productsListSchema.safeParse(data);
return validatedData.data;
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykCpw.png)

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

From the Firestore documentation on its [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Given that, it's not possible to meet your requirements with a Firestore query. The closest you can get is performing on of the range filters on the database, and then implement the rest of the filtering in your code - but that'll pretty much rule out paginating the results.

If this is a hard requirement, you'll want to use a database that is more suited for this type of query.